# Intellij IDEA font smoothing in linux

Tags: intellij-idea, java, font-smoothing

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA on Arch Linux with KDE. OpenJDK version is 1.7.0_40.

Whole IDE fonts (includes code editor) are rendered without any antialiasing and font smoothing. I set in `idea.properties` file `idea.use.default.antialiasing.in.editor` to `true`, and added in `_JAVA_OPTIONS` variable `-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true` without any effect.

What else I can try to enable font smoothing?

Answer (score 25):

[Take a look here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java_Runtime_Environment_Fonts). I remember having the same problem when running IDEA, but after adding the line mentioned in the wiki the problem goes away.

`export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=setting'`
where `setting` may be

- `off` or `false` or `default` – No anti-aliasing
- `on` – Full anti-aliasing
- `gasp` – Use the font's built-in hinting instructions
- `lcd` or `lcd_hrgb` – Anti-aliasing tuned for many popular LCD monitors
- `lcd_hbgr` – Alternative LCD monitor setting
- `lcd_vrgb` – Alternative LCD monitor setting
- `lcd_vbgr` – Alternative LCD monitor setting

Comment: okay do you have problem only with IDEA or it appears in other applications as well?

Comment: sorry for answering such late...
only in intellij idea, other apps, inlcude those who using java  such as pycharm works normal

Comment: Same problem here. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: setting useSystemAAFontSettings to LCS instead of on looks much nicer for me.

Answer (score 16):

I've found another solution [here](https://superuser.com/a/623596). 
It works for the Oracle JDK, but it may be helpful for people stumbling on this question. You have to edit the `.vmoptions` file (in my case it's `idea64.vmoptions` from `/bin`). Add these three lines:

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
-Dswing.aatext=true
-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true
```

If you encounter issues, you can remove the last line. You can test different versions for the first setting (get the options from the post above).

In addition, you can edit the font you're using and clear hinting (the post's author suggests using FontForge). I have not found this to be necessary.

Comment: I had opposite problem - Antialiasing produced artifacts which rendered the text unreadable. Setting awt.useSystemAAFontSetting to "off" did work for OpenJDK 11 (running a program which has nothing to do with IDEA). Setting swing.aatext to true or false has no effect.

Answer (score 5):

None of this ugly stuff is needed anymore. Download the latest IntelliJ (2016.1 onwards) for Linux. It includes a modified JRE with the fonts issue fixed. <strike>To fix Android Studio too make a symbolic link to the IntelliJ jre:</strike>

```
ln -s /PATH/TO/INTELLIJ/jre /PATH/TO/ANDROIDSTUDIO/jre
```

Alternatively, just open your file manager as root (assuming your IDEs are installed in the /opt directory or another system folder) and create a shortcut to IntelliJ's jre and move it to Android Studio installation folder, then rename it to 'jre'. This works for the latest android studio 2.0 but it should work with earlier versions too.

Android Studio now comes with the modified JRE so the symbolic link is not needed anymore, just download the latest version.

Comment: v2016 doesn't seem to improve font rendering for me.

Comment: @seriousdev make sure you're using an unmodified installation of IntelliJ. The font thing was an actual change they did. It's made everything _so much_ better for me.

Comment: Indeed, use the JRE delivered by JetBrains. Either download the IntelliJ directly from the JetBrains site, or use `pacman` to install IntelliJ and then add the JRE from JetBrains to the install directory.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, this is a bug in the JDK. The good news is that there's a [patch](https://gist.github.com/aleksandara/2963640) for OpenJDK that greatly improves font rendering for IntelliJ on Linux, and brings the font quality up to par with what I've seen on my Mac.

(To be clear, this is significantly better than what can be obtained by tweaking `idea.properties`.)

To install it, use the packages below:

**Ubuntu PPA** https://launchpad.net/~no1wantdthisname/+archive/openjdk-fontfix

**Arch AUR:** https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jre7-openjdk-headless-fontfix/
(I run Ubuntu/Elementary OS, so I can't vouch for this one personally)

Answer (score 3):

It won't work with OpenJDK, even with whatever `_JAVA_OPTIONS` you choose, so remove it with `sudo pacman -Rndd jdk7-openjdk jre7-openjdk jre7-openjdk-headless java-rhino` and install the Oracle JDK 8 from [Aur](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jdk/). After the installation you have to logout/login to update your java environment variables (f.e. `JAVA_HOME`). Voila, the font rendering is fine.

Enjoy!

PS: `pacman -Rndd` removes without dependencies but with the config files, expanded: `pacman --remove --nosave --nodeps --nodeps`.

[image: IntelliJ Idea Community Edition 13.1.2 with Oracle JDK8 on Arch Linux]

Comment: Definitely the easier option. No need to set additional env vars, and it works out of the box. Besides, even setting the options didn't fix it for me.

Answer (score 2):

**This applies to the current IntelliJ IDEA**

The best solution is to download **IntelliJ IDEA with the included JRE** (the default download).
This version runs on a custom JRE (Java Runtime Environment) that is patched to better handle fonts on Linux.

IntelliJ IDEA offers 2 versions for Linux, one version has an embedded JRE (the default download), while the other version doesn't have one and depends on the user's own Java installation.

**If you don't want to re-install IntelliJ, Try the following:**

1. Download and extract [this JRE](https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/download_file?file_path=jbsdk8u112b783_linux_x64.tar.gz)
2. [Switch to it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/switching-boot-jdk.html)
3. add `-Djava2d.font.loadFontConf=false` to both *idea.vmoptions* and *idea64.vmoptions* files located under *intellij_installation_folder/bin/*

N.B. The result of the first solution was a bit more nice-looking when I tried them.

*As far as my testing goes,* the [@Corneliu Dascălu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18834372/8261617) solution mentioned here **no longer works** on IntelliJ 2018 and up.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in OpenJDK. I don't think any amount of tweaking will fix this for you, it might make it a bit better, but the font rendering is broken in OpenJDK.

The most pain free fix IMHO, is to go to the AUR and install [jdk7-compat](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jdk7-compat/), which is designed to run next to your normal JDK.

Don't worry if you never used the AUR, its really straight forward. Basically, what you do is

1. insure you have base-devel installed with `pacman -S base-devel`
2. download the tar from the AUR page I linked above, uncompress it.
3. run 'makepkg -di' in the folder where you uncompressed to

and its done. Now, edit /usr/share/intellijidea-ce/bin/idea.sh and change the line which executes the program (its in the bottom of the file) so it looks like this

```
eval "/opt/java7/bin/java" $ALL_JVM_ARGS -Djb.restart.code=88 $MAIN_CLASS_NAME "$@"
```

This will make intelliJ run in the ORACLE JVM rather than the OpenJDK one, which fixes the font issues all together.

Answer (score 0):

In `/usr/share/intellijidea-ce/bin/idea.sh:`
edit this line:

```
ALL_JVM_ARGS="$VM_OPTIONS $COMMON_JVM_ARGS $IDE_JVM_ARGS $AGENT $REQUIRED_JVM_ARGS"
```

and make it like this:

```
ALL_JVM_ARGS="$VM_OPTIONS $COMMON_JVM_ARGS $IDE_JVM_ARGS $AGENT $REQUIRED_JVM_ARGS -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true"
```