# Why are fonts looking so different in different themes in intellij?

Tags: user-interface, fonts, intellij-idea, render

In IntelliJ the Darcula theme fonts look as follows

[image]

and in the default light theme they look as follows

[image]

I want to use the lighter default theme, but I find the fonts in darcula theme to be more "clear" then the default lighter theme. Can you let me know how to correct this?

PS : I am using a Linux machine

Answer (score 3):

This is controlled by `Settings -> Editor -> Color & Fonts -> Font`

However, I do not see a difference between the fonts for Darcula and the default theme :

Darcula : 
 [image]

vs.

Default: 
 [image]

both seem to use the same Consolas, Size 12 font.

#### Update

Since this is happening on Linux, from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java_Runtime_Environment_Fonts):

> Anti-aliasing of fonts is available with Oracle Java 1.6 on Linux. To
>   do this on a per user basis, add the following line to the user's
>   ~/.bashrc.
>
> export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=[setting]'

Two other useful links :

[How to fix font anti-aliasing in IntelliJ IDEA when using high DPI?](https://superuser.com/questions/614960/how-to-fix-font-anti-aliasing-in-intellij-idea-when-using-high-dpi)

[Intellij IDEA font smoothing in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346942/intellij-idea-font-smoothing-in-linux)

Comment: Hi, on linux machine they are looking different. Anyhow i am not talking about the font itself but the way they are rendered finally and shown. ( I am using the same font for both themes)

Comment: Ah!! I thought that might be the case, see the links in the Update section above.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, and finally was able to discover the following:

The issue is *not* one font smoothing, but of the Default theme and the Darcula theme using different fonts on Linux.  On my computer, the Default theme uses DejaVu Sans Mono, 12pt, but the Darcula theme uses Source Code Pro, 14pt.

[image: Darcula][image: Default-Darcula][image: Default]

If you want the Darcula Font, then go to File > Settings > Editor > Colors and Fonts > Font, make a copy of the Default scheme, and then change the font to Source Code Pro, 14pt.

See also the [Wikipedia article on Source Code Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_Pro) .

Comment: You've made my day, thank you so much! After using Eclipse it was a real hell to see these ugly fonts. With "Source Code Pro" font it's still not as good, as Eclipse, but much better anyway. You literally saved my eyes from burning, I would give you 100 points, if I only could!

Comment: @nucleo I've started using the Source Code Pro Semibold variant, but that's just a personal preference.